# Do library users always need to recompile when the library switches Compiler from 1.5 to 1.6?

Tags: java, jvm, backwards-compatibility, java-6, java-5

Please consider the following scenario: A Java Framework and a bunch of application-plugins are deployed as a Java SE Client Application. The Client *Runtime* is Java SE 6, whereas the framework as well as the application-plugins is *compiled* with Java SE 5.

Now the framework is recompiled with Java SE 6, the application-plugins remain unchanged (compiled with Java SE 5).

Assuming the framework "interface" (classes/interfaces directly used by the application-plugins) remains compilable with Java SE 5 (language level and API) the question is: Do the application-plugins need to be recompiled (against the recompiled framework) in order to be usable together at runtime (with Java SE 6)?

Maybe the question comes down to this: Under what circumstance may it make any problem when "SE6-classfiles" (v50) are used by "SE5-classfiles" (v49) within an SE6-runtime?

Comment: AFAIK, You can run jars compiled with Java 1.0 on a Java 7.0 JVM.  It is highly unlikely there is a good reason to recompile as the `javac` doesn't optimise the code, the JIT does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no [(binary) incompatible changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html) in the interfaces/classes and the runtime VM supports the new classfile version, then there should be no issues.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Just to make sure I haven't overlooked something. Thank you! The final prove will be done in production environment - hopefully I won't need to come back to this ;-)